# How to execute a nodejs function from the python code?

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.7

Our application uses python and serverside nodejs.
There is python code which sends notifications to users. When a notification is send we need to send that info to a third part tool for analytics. We are using python 2.7and the analytic tool has SDK based on python 3.
So, we planned to use the node SDK of the analytic tool. So we will write the code call the analytic tool api from the nodejs code.
But the node js function should be triggered when a notification is send.
So, in python code, once the notification is sent to users, we can call the nodejs function which will call the analytics api.

I tried checking in the google but didnt find any reliable examples.

Comment: Python2 is end of life. What's preventing that from being upgraded? Otherwise, your question would simply be "how to run a external command" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command#89243

Comment: What is the analytic tool in particular? Chances are it's just making an HTTP request somewhere, and you can well do that in Python.